# Extending SonataUser - Update setters getters

Tags: doctrine, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.1

I extended SonataUser with SonataEasyExtends so I have now a `Application/Sonata/UserBundle`

I have added a field in the model `Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml`

Tried to update the setters & getters with

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User
```

Seems to go well. Now trying to update the database

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Access level to Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User::$groups must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User) or weaker in /home/glide/bouygues/src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User.php on line 26

So the question is: how should I properly update getters & setters in `Entity/User.php`, should I have to reuse EasyExtends ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem and the simple solution was to change the declaration of the groups variable from public to protected:

```
  /**
   * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   */
   protected $groups;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you paste your entity and the xml config?

the error tends to mean your variable "$groups" needs to be protected so its either being declared as a "normal" var or private.